# How to configure read receipts for email subscriptions?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there any way that we can determine if the recipient has seen the report that was delivered through a subscription by email option?

Answer (score 0):

No, the "Read Receipts" is configured on the E-mail server. It is not a supported configuration of the email notification on Reporting Services. [Microsoft Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5592a5c7-b534-4aad-8e2a-7ee4b6a57287/how-can-we-get-read-receipts-for-ssrs-subscription-emails?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Here is the reference for [E-Mail Delivery in Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/e-mail-delivery-in-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017). It describes report server e-mail delivery operation and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly supported, but you could build a workaround for it. For example, you could have a link provided the email that you request them to click on. The link would contain an ID and go to a site/report that logs the ID.

You could even go a step further and just send a link. They would have to click it to see the report and that could be logged.